# Windows Phone 8 SQLite + FTS3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sqlite, fts3

I would like to use sqlite with fts3 support on the windows phone 8.

I downloaded sqlite vsix package for the windows phone 8. But the sqlite does not support FTS3. Is there any way how to use SQLite with FTS support in the Windows Phone 8? Should I compile my own sqlite version from source code and set the SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 flag?

Thank you
Myth.